# Converter agent uninstallation

Tags: vmware-converter

How to manually uninstall VMware converter agent from RHEL5 linux server after sucessfully P2V?

Comment: anyone? please? I really need this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the VMware Converter README:

> (7) Uninstall Converter Standalone
>
> The executable that uninstalls Converter Standalone is located at
>   /usr/bin/ directory by default.
>   Navigate to this directory and type ./vmware-uninstall-converter.pl

If for some reason you can't find it, you can always try `locate vmware-uninstall-converter.pl` on a standard RHEL5 box.

The file is also included in the tar file distributed by VMware (which you can download from http://www.vmware.com/download/converter/)